# Terminal on OSX stuck at login screen, 80x24 error

Tags: macos, bash, mac, terminal

I did try all methods given in prior threads.
Problem: login, blank screen, 80x24 on Terminal

1. I cannot find any file called com.apple.Terminal... in Library/Preferences that I could delete, nor I have done that before
2. I have tried to change the preferences in Terminal to use /bin/bash, no effect
3. I DO in fact remember editing/creating a bashrc file though a terminal (following advice on installing pandas in python). This probably caused the problem.

Now I am stuck and would love to get the terminal back without having a troublesome reinstall.

Comment: Use the GUI to create a second account with admin privs (if you don't have one already), and then log into that account. If the Terminal works in that account, you don't have a system-wide problem, so you just need to fix the broken account. Use the Terminal in the new admin account to move/rename any shell startup scripts in the "broken" account, in case those scripts are causing the problem you're seeing.

Comment: @Spiff Terminal does in fact work in my admin account, the problem lies in my user account. Thank you for the suggestion to rename the shell startup scripts in the broken account. However, I am new to UNIX and have no idea how to do so... 
As said before, the problem likely is caused by the creation of a bashrc file, which I created in UNIX I believe.

Comment: **Update: all of a sudden it works again today, though I did not change anything. Restarting did not help, but maybe logging out and in again.